# Garbage Collection and Callbacks

Tags: java, android, callback, garbage-collection

If I have object `A`, which calls DAO object `B` to perform some database update - Once `B's` function completes it calls a call back function in `A` (`A.finishProcess()`) does this create memory issues? I mean does `B` then remain in memory until `A` completes? or is `B` still removed with GC?

I ask this as I'm considering using call backs instead of returning a "result" object or code from `B`.

In short, is it better design (and memory usage) wise to "return" an object of results rather than using a callback to a calling object?

PS: Please ignore specific's ie, it doesn't mention `AsycnTask`, its a contrived situation to get my question across :)

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all about references. As long as you don't store/keep any (strong) references around (i.e. proper deregistration, clearing references once the object is no longer in use, etc), you don't have to worry as the object will properly be handled by GC.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll just make sure to clear references once I'm done

Answer (score 1):

When you have DAO object you will be registering your class for the respective call backs.

Simply de-register for the call backs and remove the references of B class in your class.

Something like below (here take "b" is an Object of class B).

```
b.removeListener(this);
b = null;
```

This will tell JVM that the references no longer exist to class B and GC will clear it out from the Memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think your use of callback will cause memory usage issues. If not, I feel confused already. If you supply code, it will be easier for us to understand your idea.

The best documentation I read so far on memory issues or memory leaks, as titled by IBM is at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-leaks/ .

If you get an object of array, list, or whatever, then it's easy to deference it when you can and as soon as possible. I would normally vote for result objects, as you termed it.